# Laravel 4 : get current id to put id's from 2 tables in a third table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, many-to-many, eloquent

In laravel 4 I want to get the current id of the band I'm making so I can store it with the festival id I'm attaching the band with. How can I get the current id in laravel 4 using eloquent?

```
public function store()
    {
        $input = Input::all();

        $rules = array(
            'band_name'      => 'required',
            'band_members' => 'required',
            'band_genre' => 'required',
            'band_startdate' => 'required'
        );
        $validator = Validator::make($input, $rules);

        if($validator->passes())
        {
            $bands = new Band();

            $band_festivals = new BandFestival();

            //here I want the current id of the band i'm making to store it in the band_festivals table
            $band_festivals->band_id = Input::get('band_id'); 

            $band_festivals->festival_id = Input::get('festival_id');

            $bands->band_id = Input::get('band_id');
            $bands->band_name = $input['band_name'];
            $bands->band_members = $input['band_members'];
            $bands->band_genre = $input['band_genre'];
            $bands->band_startdate = $input['band_startdate'];

            $bands->save();

            $band_festivals->save();

            Session::flash('message', 'Successfully created festival!');
            return Redirect::to('bands');
        }
        else {
            return Redirect::to('bands/create')->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you use relations for this? You don't need that `$band_festival` at all.

Comment: I have 3 tables bands, festivals and band_festivals. So many festivals have many bands and vice versa.

Comment: Yeah, I know. Just wondering why dont you use `belongsToMany` relation for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the band first...

```
$bands->save();
```

Then use the `$bands` model to get the id for your `$band_festivals` model:

```
$band_festivals->band_id = $bands->id; 
$band_festivals->save();
```

Comment: Thanks this helped and made it work. $bands->id should be $bands->band_id in my example ;-)